# How to async copy files in .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, file-io, c#-2.0

I'm trying to async copy files from one drive to another using .NET 2.0 in a WinForms application. I've got this working in .NET 4.5 using this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys(v=vs.110).aspx -- I'm looking for the .NET 2.0 equivalent of this (the 2.0 version in the guide deals with image processing).

Alternatively, are there any good frameworks out there that can handle this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

async/await uses ThreadPool under hood. So if you want to copy file and hide proggress bar you can use tis code

```
    public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

    private void CopyFiles()
    {
        ....
    }

    public void HideProgressBar()
    {
        ...
    }

    void CopyFilesAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x =>
        {
            CopyFiles();
            BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(HideProgressBar));
        });
    }
```